# How to make threads write their numbers in reverse order using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

So I have a task. I need to make 8 threads an make them write their numbers in reverse order. I know how to make them write in natural order, but really confused about the reverse one. Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: then please at least show your code in natural order.

Comment: just a sidenote: if you require threads to do their job in some specific order, you should rethink if you really need seperate threads. I guess this is just an exercise, though a stupid one imho

Comment: You need to show some code. E.g you state "I know how to make them write in natural order". You could at least show the code for that. Show what you have tried to do. Why do you need the threads in reverse order? I would not be surprised by that requirement at the final state of an algorithm but a specific example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the purpose of what you are asking but this works

```
 #include "omp.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {

#pragma omp parallel
{
      int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      for(int i=nthreads-1; i>=0; i--)
      {
            #pragma omp barrier
            {
                  if(i==omp_get_thread_num())
                  {
                        #pragma omp critical
                        cout << "I am thread "<< i <<endl;
                  }
            }
      }
}
}
```

8 threads it outputs

```
I am thread 7
I am thread 6
I am thread 5
I am thread 4
I am thread 3
I am thread 2
I am thread 1
I am thread 0
```

Comment: I don't really think this is correct (besides that it's bound to accessible threads number), can you explain?

Comment: thank you! thought barrier should be used in some way, but didn't got how.

Comment: I don't even get the question, so assessing if it's correct can only be done by Peltatum. Maybe you think the "#pragma omp critical" is too much. You are probably right it is being overprotective...